# Strip the HTML tags from BLOB storage content using azure cognitive search indexer

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I have setup an indexer with blob storage data source for the html file and with the following configuration of **parsingMode="default"** and **dataToExtract="contentAndMetadata"** the **content** field value is always the raw HTML
But I want the content without html tags.

The file extension is ".html" for the document and content type is "text/html"

```
{
  "name" : "my-blob-indexer",
  "dataSourceName" : "my-blob-datasource",
  "targetIndexName" : "my-search-index",
  "parameters": {
      "batchSize": null,
      "maxFailedItems": null,
      "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": null,
      "base64EncodeKeys": null,
      "configuration": {
          "indexedFileNameExtensions" : ".html",
          "excludedFileNameExtensions" : ".png,.jpeg",
          "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
          "parsingMode": "default"
      }
  },
  "schedule" : { },
  "fieldMappings" : [ ]
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage
I'm using this document as reference to index data the blob storage

Comment: Hi, could you please state the question you are asking?

Comment: Updated the question, I want the html tags get removed for the content field and only store plain text content.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

Comment: "Default" is the right setting to remove HTML tags. Can you provide a sample response of your "content" field?